# Python KeyError when trying to access Dictionary Index 0: dict[0]

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, keyerror

Edit: I've moved this question to a new post: [Python: KeyError when Calling Valid Key/Index in Dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117272/python-keyerror-when-calling-valid-key-index-in-dict)

I'm successfully receiving some properly formatted JSON data via websocket:

```
while True:
    result = ws.recv()    
    result = json.loads(result)
```

I can loop through the dictionary like this:

```
    for i in result:
        print (i)
        print (result[i])
```

This will print "Valid_Key" and "Some_value".
However, if I try to access this by key name or index, I will receive a "KeyError".

```
print (result[0])
```

This will result in:
**KeyError: 0**

```
print (result["Valid_Key"])
```

This will result in:
**KeyError: 'Valid_Key'**

How can I access dictionary data by index or key in Python?

Example with no error:
https://s17.postimg.org/e11brl99r/Success.jpg

Example with KeyError:
https://s17.postimg.org/t9r95mxvz/Key_Error.jpg

Comment: You **cannot** index dictionaries as they have no particular order. You can, however, *index a list in which the dictionary items have been cast into*. In your case, that would be `list(result.items())[0]` (or `list(result.values())[0]`). But, note, that there is no notion of **first** or **nth** item in a dictionary. So the above code **can produce different outputs for the same input**. You have been warned ;)

Comment: Actually [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=values#dictionary-view-objects) guarantees that if no changes are made between iterations they will directly correspond.

Comment: @DanielRoseman What if you close your script and load it again? Or receive the exact same `json` dictionary again?

Comment: If the `result` dict has a key of `"Valid_Key"` then `result["Valid_Key"]` should give you the value associated with that key. Maybe that converted JSON object isn't exactly what you think it is. Can you show us an example `result` that gives the error you're talking about?

Comment: @PM2Ring That's what I though, I added 2 screenshots, please check those.

Comment: I still have no idea what your data looks like. And please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you post output of `type(result)`, `str(result)[:10]`, `str(result)[-10:]`?

Comment: @PM2Ring Here is the output from print (result): {'type': 'ticker', 'sequence': 4779671311, 'product_id': 'BTC-USD', 'price': '15988.29000000', 'open_24h': '14566.71000000', 'volume_24h': '18276.75612545', 'low_24h': '15988.29000000', 'high_24h': '16102.00000000', 'volume_30d': '1018642.48337033', 'best_bid': '15988.28', 'best_ask': '15988.29', 'side': 'buy', 'time': '2018-01-05T15:38:21.568000Z', 'trade_id': 32155934, 'last_size': '0.02420000'}

Comment: @sKwa type(result)= <class 'dict'> str(result)[:10]= {'type': ' str(result)[-10:]= 00006238'}

Comment: You should put that data into your question, inside a code block to preserve formatting. With that `result` dict, `print(result['price'])` gives me `15988.29000000`, as expected.

Comment: So to the original question, why am I getting a KeyError when calling the same code with the same Dict? When I call: print (result['price']) I get a KeyError: 'price' ? The only way I will not get a KeyError, is if I print (result['price']) inside of a for loop: for i in result: (screenshot shows this)

Comment: I've made a new question from the problem because PM 2Ring was not able to replicate my error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117272/python-keyerror-when-calling-valid-key-index-in-dict

Answer (score 0):

The problem in while True: on first iteration you got a result 15800.0, but on second iteration your dictionary do not contains key = 'price'

Create a guard in while True loop, like in for loop:

```
while True:
    result = ws.recv()
    result = json.loads(result)
    if result and 'price' in result:
        print(result['price'])
    ...
```

Thanks to sKwa, answered here:
[Python: KeyError when Calling Valid Key/Index in Dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117272/python-keyerror-when-calling-valid-key-index-in-dict)