# Python: KeyError when Calling Valid Key/Index in Dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, keyerror

I have some JSON data that I'm pulling from a websocket:

```
while True:
    result = ws.recv()    
    result = json.loads(result)
```

Here is Print(result):

```
{'type': 'ticker', 'sequence': 4779671311, 'product_id': 'BTC-USD', 'price': '15988.29000000', 'open_24h': '14566.71000000', 'volume_24h': '18276.75612545', 'low_24h': '15988.29000000', 'high_24h': '16102.00000000', 'volume_30d': '1018642.48337033', 'best_bid': '15988.28', 'best_ask': '15988.29', 'side': 'buy', 'time': '2018-01-05T15:38:21.568000Z', 'trade_id': 32155934, 'last_size': '0.02420000'}
```

Now I want to access the **'price'** value.

```
print (result['price'])
```

This results with a KeyError:

```
File "C:/Users/Selzier/Documents/Python/temp.py", line 43, in <module>
    print (result['price'])
KeyError: 'price'
```

However, if I perform a loop on the (results) data, then I can successfully print both **i** and **result[i]**

```
  for i in result:        
        if i == "price":
            print (i)
            print (result[i])
```

Which will print the following data:

```
price
16091.00000000
```

Why do I get a 'KeyError' when calling:

```
result['price']
```

AND

```
result[0]
```

When I'm not inside of the **'for i in result'** loop?

Comment: `print (result['price'])` works fine for me using the example dict you posted above.

Comment: You need to show the full code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you always gets a valid "result" value, in every cycle of your infinite loop?
This could be a lead, since if in one of your iterations the results are invalid, so of-course your keys iteration won't fail, but direct-access does.

Comment: The problem in `while True`: on first iteration you got a result `15800.0`, but on second iteration your dictionary do not contains `key = 'price'`.

Comment: You should have fixed [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110167/python-keyerror-when-trying-to-access-dictionary-index-0-dict0) rather than starting a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a guard in `while True` loop, like in `for` loop:

```
while True:
    result = ws.recv()
    result = json.loads(result)
    if result and 'price' in result:
        print(result['price'])
    ...
```

(read my comment)

[image]

Comment: Thank you sKwa, fixed! I was trying to check if the Len() of the dictionary was > 0 but that wasn't working either.